# XML to PDF convert

Tags: pdf, xml

Here in my firm we receive an XML file that is supposed to be some sort of invoice, but it is not visible. I tried to convert it to a PDF file with any online PDF converter, but the file remains the same XML text, with no document view on it. I tried also PDFelement Pro or similar, but nothing happens. Any suggestions? Any help will be appreciated. I must make this XML file into a readable document for the needs of the firm.

Comment: XML has no visual outlook or design, it is just data. An analogy to what you're asking is to get a PDF of SQL database. To visualize your XML-data, I would first XSLT (see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/displaying-xml-using-xslt/) it into HTML5, which can be printed as PDF.

Answer (score 1):

xml is just a plain text file.
There's no [simple] way to know what was meant to be used to correctly interpret it.

Ask whoever sent it to you what it's from, or if they have a more portable format they could send it in.